# HTTPS redirect not working without www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I added SSL with CloudFlare to my website.
When I enter the website with *www.example.com* everything goes well.
But when I enter the website with *example.com* it will not redirect to HTTPS.

---

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

# RewriteRules
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=302,NE,L]

# ErrorDocument
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

I don't understand a lot from htaccess, I hope you can help.
The goal is to have *http://www.example.com* and *http://example.com* redirect to *https://example.com*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CloudFlare, use:

```
# RewriteRules
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^ https://exemple.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Instead of your first RewriteCond,RewriteRule 2 lines

Answer (score 0):

Change your RewriteCondition to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
```

to allow both **www** or **non-www**

Comment: I got an error "too many redirects".
But the comment above is working, but thank you :)